# Magento 2 image helper with category image url

Tags: magento2, image, helper

I want to use helper for category image.

Right now I,m getting category image like this :

```
$image = $cat->getImageUrl();
```

But I want to keep frame to false so how can I do it with category images?

Comment: For which page you want to looking for image url?

Comment: I've one widget in which I'm showing category images so it can be on any pag e